# how to convert a list value into int

Tags: python, list, casting

i have a pyodbc row with value (9, )
I am trying to read the value into a simple integer variable, and i find that its so hard to do so. (i am new to python so i probably miss something dumb)

doing a simple `int(a_row[0])` get -

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'pyodbc.Row'
```

i try to cast the row into a list first, and its the same result

i had to force it into a integer value to work

```
row_id=(2, )

temp_num=0

temp_num = [number for number in row_id[0]]

temp_num=int(temp_num[0])
```

i just find it really bizarre that i have to do something so silly, so it must be my fault, can anyone enlighten me, where i got it wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the row type supports iteration but not indexing.

Comment: Are you sure you have __a__ pyodbc row and not a sequence of rows?

Comment: Your sample code 1) doesn't run, and 2) doesn't accurately represent your problem. For advice on how to create a more useful sample, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://SSCCE.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution isn't forcing it into an integer; it is creating an array of the elements (the `Row`s) in `row_id[0]`, and then extracting the first one.  So you could have just done `a_row[0][0]` initially.

Comment: ah, ok, i knew i must be doing something silly. is it because to extract values from rows objects we must do that?

Answer (score 0):

The output of **fetchall** of a query is a list of **pyodbc.Row**s:

```
>>> x=cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM my_tbl limit 5;').fetchall()
>>> print(x)      # list of elements of type pyodbc.Row
[(3, ), (2, ), (0, ), (5, ), (1, )]
>>> type(x[0])
pyodbc.Row
```

to get actual integers pulled by the query above do this

```
>>> [row[0] for row in x]
[3, 2, 0, 5, 1]
```