# Convert pyodbc.row to int list

Tags: python, list, pyodbc

This doesn't seem like it would be very difficult but I'm at a loss.

How can I take a pyodbc.row and convert it to a int list? This is driving my crazy.

Comment: This did the trick.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25652851/how-to-convert-a-list-value-into-int

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple list comprehension works for me:

```python
row = crsr.fetchone()
row_as_list = [x for x in row]
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: simple and efficient, congratulations